# Printing groups of key/value pairs in hash

Tags: perl, hash

How can I print a hash in Perl, such that 3 key value pairs are printed on each line?

```
print %hash;
```

This will print key value pairs each in a line.

Comment: Almost nobody is reading the question.

Answer (score 3):

To display the hash, so "that 3[n] key value pairs are printed on each line", you can use a counter (`$n`) and `%` (modulo op) to determine when to print a "`\n`". Demo:

```
use Modern::Perl;

my %h = ();
for (0..7) {
    $h{$_} = chr(65 + $_);
}
print %h, "\n";
my $cols = +$ARGV[0] || 5;
my $n = -$cols;
for my $key (keys %h) {
    print $key, ' => ', $h{$key}, 0 == ++$n % $cols ? "\n" : "\t\t";
}
print $n % $cols ? "\n------" : "------";
```

output:

```
perl -w 31444449.pl 1
6G4E1B3D0A7H2C5F
6 => G
4 => E
1 => B
3 => D
0 => A
7 => H
2 => C
5 => F
------

perl -w 31444449.pl
6G4E1B3D0A7H2C5F
6 => G          4 => E          1 => B          3 => D          0 => A
7 => H          2 => C          5 => F
------

perl -w 31444449.pl 3
6G4E1B3D0A7H2C5F
6 => G          4 => E          1 => B
3 => D          0 => A          7 => H
2 => C          5 => F
------
```

Borodin's solutions, however, is simpler.

See [mpapec answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/97124/4458) for a much improved version.

Comment: @Downvoter - please tell me what I did wrong. I really want to improve my answer.

Comment: It was me and I apologise; like most people I apparently didn't see the requirement for 3 key value pairs. I can't un-downvote until you edit the answer though

Comment: @fugu - thanks for the feedback, no need to apologise.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple way to do this is to copy all the keys and values to an array, and then print six (three pairs) of those at a time

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %h = map { $_ => 1 } 'A' .. 'H';

my @kv = %h;
while ( my @row = splice @kv, 0, 6 ) {
  print "@row\n";
}
```

#### output

```
B 1 C 1 A 1
D 1 E 1 G 1
F 1 H 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [natatime from List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#natatime-EXPR-LIST):

```
use List::MoreUtils qw/natatime/;

my $it = natatime 6, %ENV;
while (my @vals = $it->()) {
  print "@vals\n";
}
```

`List::MoreUtils` isn't in core modules, you need to install it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: It needs to be emphasized that `List::MoreUtils` isn't a core module and will probably need  to be installed

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All. I tried this and it worked.

```
my @keylist=sort keys %hash;
 my $counter=0;
 foreach(@keylist){
  #printing the key value pairs
  printf "%-15s :%3d     ",$_,$hash{$_};
  $counter++;
  if($counter==3){
    $counter=0;
   print "\n";
  }
 }
 print "\n";
```

Answer (score -3):

If you really just want to print hash and check the values for debugging or for analysing then use

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\%hash);
```

This print hash keys and values at any n number of levels